# XmlUnit 2.x compare 2 xmls fail because of difference in namespace prefix

Tags: java, xmlunit-2

- Comparing two xmls using XmlUnit 2.2.1 in java.
- The only difference between the documents is in the namespace prefix.

Here is code snippet to reproduce:

```
 @Test 
 public void testDifferentPrefix() {
            final String control = "<ns:a xmlns:ns='abc'><b attr=\"xyz\"></b></ns:a>";
            final String test = "<ns1:a xmlns:ns1='abc'><b attr=\"xyz\"></b></ns1:a>";

            Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(control))
                              .withTest(Input.fromString(test))
                              .build();
            Assert.assertFalse(myDiff.toString(), myDiff.hasDifferences());        
}
```

when the above test is run, it is failing with below error:

> Expected namespace prefix 'ns' but was 'ns1' - comparing  at /pfx:a[1] to  at /pfx:a[1]
>   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
>       at NewEmptyJUnitTest.testDifferentPrefix(NewEmptyJUnitTest.java:95)

What should be corrected in order to avoid the error? I believe that am missing something trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By not specifying any `DifferenceEvaluator` you are implicitly using `DifferenceBuilders.DEFAULT` for which a different namespace prefixes are "SIMILAR" differences.

If you want to ignore "SIMILAR" differences you must set `checkForSimilar()` on the `DiffBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you Stefan for the quick response, that resolves the issue.

Comment: Hello Stefan, but i have some custom DifferenceEvaluator and need to ignore namesprefix what shall i do. I combine them by DifferenceEvaluators.chain(Default, new MyEvaluator("field to ignore")) - it does not work