# Skip comparison xml order between two xml documents

Tags: soapui, xmlunit

I have two xml documents and the content in those documents same. But in one document namespaces order is different when comparing with other xml. I need to skip the order of the namespaces when comparing via soapui. Im using xmlunit

Comment: Are you using `DifferenceEvaluator` ?

Comment: Are you using `DifferenceEvaluator/DiffBuilder` or `DifferenceEngine` ? In that case [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlunit/discussion/73274/thread/29782e1e/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524286/xmlunit-ignore-xmlns) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862681/xmlunit-2-x-compare-2-xmls-fail-because-of-difference-in-namespace-prefix) might help. I simply use it like `XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true)` then `def result = XMLUnit.compareXML(expectedXml, actualXml)`